# How to make widgets packed within gtk.Box (VBox/HBox) resizable by the user

Tags: gtk, resize, pygtk, vbox, hbox

Is it possible to make the widgets within a box resizable by the user? Cheers!

Example:

> hbox.pack_start(my_scrolled_window_1, expand=True, fill=True, padding=0)
>   hbox.pack_start(my_vseparator, expand=False, fill=False, padding=5)
>   hbox.pack_start(my_scrolled_window_2, expand=True, fill=True, padding=0)
>   ...

I would like the user being able to drag the VSeparator to give more or less size to my_scrolled_window_1/2.

Reference: http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkbox.html

Is the common approach maybe to put the widgets recursively into a gtk.Paned (VPaned/HPaned) as in `Pane(w1,Pane(w2,Pane(w3,Pane(w4,w5))))` for say five widgets w?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is common to use a hierarchy of GtkPaned (V or H) widgets to achieve this. Sadly, there is no widget for nicely adding an arbitrary number of children and have separators between them.